# Forgot password validation

Tags: php, html

Here is my project structure,
classes-> forgotpassword.php ,,

index.php is in the outer side of the project.
Requirement is, Whenever the non registered user clicks on forgotpassword link. It should redirect him to my SIGNUP page.

What I'm doing is,

```
else{
      //$link_address = '';
echo 'Hi user, You are not yet registered to Wings2Roots<br><br><a href="index.php"><br/>Please click here to SIGNUP</a>';
   }
```

So, whenever I'm clicking on SIGNUP , it's redirecting me to http://localhost/ProjectName/classes/index.php. As a result it displays File not found.
  Problem here is, I don't want that classes in that url.

Comment: A common solution that I see very often is to have a "BaseUrl" that is appended to every link. Something like `<a href="<?= $base_url ?>/index.php">Link</a>`. Where `$base_url` would be `/ProjectName`.

Comment: Where is your index.php actually located in your project? If you saved it in classes folder, then you should remove it from there (if you don't want it there).

Comment: It's in root directory. I can't remove it from there because I used session objects there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
<a href="../index.php"><br/>Please click here to SIGNUP</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `index.php`. to `/index.php`.

```
<a href="/index.php"><br/>Please click here to SIGNUP</a>
```

Or, you could create a `base_url()` function that is always going to point to the root directory, then do something like:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/index.php"><br/>Please click here to SIGNUP</a>
```